# How to measure the execution time of a code without actually running the code in R?

Tags: r

Can I use `microbenchmark to calculate the approximate time it would take to execute my code in R? I am running some code and I can see that it takes a lot of hours to execute? I don't want to run my code all that time. I want to see the approximate execution time without actually running the code in R.

Comment: How would this even conceptually work? If you don’t want to execute your code *at all*, then what you want is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://www.biomart.org/other/biomart_0.9_0_documentation.pdf) — i.e. provably impossible.

Comment: Even if you want to run your code for “a bit” and extrapolate from this, there are problems: For instance, your algorithm could consist of parts, the first of which takes 2 h and the second takes 5 s. So even if you could just execute “a bit”, and even if the profiler would somehow know “how far along” it went, it would then extrapolate that the second part of the code takes as long as the first, unless the profiler already knew that this wasn’t the case (and how would it know? We’re back to square one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running your code on smaller problems to see how it scales

```
> fun0 = function(n) { x = integer(); for (i in seq_len(n)) x = c(x, i); x }
> p = microbenchmark(fun0(1000), fun0(2000), fun0(4000), fun0(8000), fun0(16000),
+                    times=20)
> p
Unit: milliseconds
        expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max
  fun0(1000)   1.627601   1.697958   1.995438   1.723522   2.289424   2.935609
  fun0(2000)   5.691456   6.333478   6.745057   6.928060   7.056893   8.040366
  fun0(4000)  23.343611  24.487355  24.987870  24.854968  25.554553  26.088183
  fun0(8000)  92.517691  95.827525 104.900161  97.305930 112.924961 136.434998
 fun0(16000) 365.495320 369.697953 380.981034 374.456565 390.829214 411.203191
 neval
    20
    20
    20
    20
    20
```

Doubling the problem size leads to exponentially slower execution; visualize as

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(p, aes(x=expr, y=log(time))) + geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth(method="lm", aes(x=as.integer(expr)))
```

This is terrible news for big problems!

Investigate alternative implementations that scale better while returning the same answer, both as the problem increases in size and at a given problem size. First make sure your algorithms / implementations get the same answer

```
> ## linear, ok
> fun1 = function(n) { x = integer(n); for (i in seq_len(n)) x[[i]] = i; x }
> identical(fun0(100), fun1(100))
[1] TRUE
```

then see how the new algorithm scales with problem size

```
> microbenchmark(fun1(100), fun1(1000), fun1(10000))
Unit: microseconds
        expr      min       lq      mean    median         uq       max neval
   fun1(100)   86.260   97.558  121.5591  102.6715   107.6995  1058.321   100
  fun1(1000)  845.160  902.221  932.7760  922.8610   945.6305  1915.264   100
 fun1(10000) 8776.673 9100.087 9699.7925 9385.8560 10310.6240 13423.718   100
```

Explore more algorithms, especially those that replace *iteration* with *vectorization*

```
> ## linear, faster -- *nano*seconds
> fun2 = seq_len
> identical(fun1(100), fun2(100))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(fun2(100), fun2(1000), fun2(10000))
Unit: nanoseconds
        expr   min      lq     mean median    uq   max neval
   fun2(100)   417   505.0   587.53    553   618  2247   100
  fun2(1000)  2126  2228.5  2774.90   2894  2986  5511   100
 fun2(10000) 19426 19741.0 25390.93  27177 28209 43418   100
```

Comparing algorithms at specific sizes

```
> n = 1000; microbenchmark(fun0(n), fun1(n), fun2(n), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
    expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 fun0(n) 1625.797 1637.949 2018.6295 1657.1195 2800.272 2857.400    10
 fun1(n)  819.448  843.988  874.9445  853.9290  910.871 1006.582    10
 fun2(n)    2.158    2.386    2.5990    2.6565    2.716    3.055    10
> n = 10000; microbenchmark(fun0(n), fun1(n), fun2(n), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
    expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq        max
 fun0(n) 157010.750 157276.699 169905.4745 159944.5715 192185.973 197389.965
 fun1(n)   8613.977   8630.599   9212.2207   9165.9300   9394.605  10299.821
 fun2(n)     19.296     19.384     20.7852     20.8595     21.868     22.435
 neval
    10
    10
    10
```

shows the increasing importance of a sensible implementation as problem size increases.